# jsPlumb anchor shape

Tags: css, anchor, css-shapes, endpoint, jsplumb

Will someone be so kind to tell me how to change the shape of an anchor in jsPlumb?
I would like to have semi-circles on the left and right sides of the boxes as anchors.

The problem seems to be to get the anchors to use the CSS for their shape.

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2uvy1uju/11/

You can ignore the following code:
The JS:

```
var startpointOptions = {isSource: true, anchor: "RightMiddle", endpoint: ['Rectangle', {width: 40, height: 40, cssClass: "outArc"}], paintStyle: {fillStyle:"red"}};
var endpointOptions = {isTarget: true, anchor: "LeftMiddle", endpoint: ['Dot', {radius: 20, cssClass: "inArc"}], paintStyle: {fillStyle:"blue"}};

var startpoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint($('#theDiv'), startpointOptions);
var endpoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint($('#theDiv'), endpointOptions);
```

The CSS:

```
.inArc {float:left; background-color: darkblue; height: 40px; width: 20px; border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0; margin-top:30px;}
.outArc {float:right; background-color: darkred; height: 40px; width: 20px; border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px; margin-top:30px;}
```

Like this:

[image]

Comment: use images or apply CSS to attain desired width (did latter recently).

Comment: @coding_idiot: Thanks a lot for the advice. Do you have an example of the CSS method perhaps, because I can't seem to get it working?

Comment: can you create a fiddle to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: just recalled, used z-index to get half of the circle of endpoint appear behind the div

Comment: Thanks, it helps. It will be great if the other half doesn't stick out from the div. I've made a jsFiddle and will edit my question to contain it in a minute. The problem seems to be that the CSS is not used for the anchor shape. If you have a solution, you can answer the question if you like.